# Rails app internal links not working, but direct urls are

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink

I have an app running on Ror4 but don't seem to get my links working. Whereever I have a

```
<%= link_to "Get Started", get_started_path %>
```

or similar in my code, clicking it doesn't do anything. but if I type the address localhost:3000/get-started it correctly brings me to my page

Here's my routes.rb

```
 match '/get-started' => 'static#get-started', via: 'get'
 root 'static#index'
 match '/thank-you' => 'static#thank-you', via: 'get'
 match '/how-it-works' => 'static#how-it-works', via: 'get'
match '/get-started' => 'static#get-started', via: 'get'
match '/get-newsletter' => 'static#newsletter-signup', via: 'get'
match '/privacy-policy' => 'static#privacy-policy', via: 'get'
match '/terms-and-conditions' => 'static#terms-and-conditions', via: 'get'
```

The issue is the same for all of the links as well as links generated by e.g. devise. Which leads me to believe that it's not a controller issue. A click on

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

also doesn't work. This befaviour is the same in my local dev environment and on a server. 
Clicks on direct links e.g. http://www.google.com do work and so does:

```
<%= f.submit "Next" %>
```

Actually no idea what the problem is. The dev console doesn't throw errors and the rails console doesn't either.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you check the generated HTML? If the links appear correct there, I suspect a JS issue...

Comment: After posting this questions I found that when I render a page with :layout => false the links work correctly

Comment: @awendt if you post an answer with that, I'll give you the points for it. Thanks for the hint!!!

Answer (score 0):

As awendt pointed out in his comment it turned out to be a javascript issue. When I added a render :layout => false to a view the links did work, and I could eliminate the javascript by including them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

try to set in `routes.rb` something like:

```
get '/get-started', to: 'static#get-started', as: 'get_started'
```

then do `bundle exec rake routes` in order to see right url variable (should be `get_started_path`)

in rails 4 it's better idea to use `get` or `post` rather then `match` in `routes.rb`